# Why x must be non negative integer using binom.test

Tags: r, statistics

Why am I getting this error?

> Error in binom.test(0.555, 10) : 'x' must be nonnegative and integer

Comment: See the function's help: x must be the number of successes, not the proportion of successes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first input, `x`, should be an integer of length 1 with the number of successes or of length 2 with the number of successes and failures, as below.

Please see `?binom.test` for more details.

```
binom.test(c(round(0.555*10), round((1-0.555)*10)))
```

> ```
>   Exact binomial test
>
> data:  c(round(0.555 * 10), round((1 - 0.555) * 10))
> number of successes = 6, number of trials = 10, p-value = 0.7539
> alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.5
> 95 percent confidence interval:
>  0.2623781 0.8784477
> sample estimates:
> probability of success 
>                    0.6
> ```

From the docs:

> ```
> Usage
>
> binom.test(x, n, p = 0.5,
>            alternative = c("two.sided", "less", "greater"),
>            conf.level = 0.95)
> Arguments
>
> x 
> number of successes, or a vector of length 2 giving the numbers of successes and failures, respectively.
> n 
> number of trials; ignored if x has length 2.
> ```